# Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned

Tags: support, announcement

You may have seen a similar policy announced on [StackOverflow's meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). While it's not [enforced network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide/385002#385002), we the moderators feel that the risk of posting plausible-sounding generated answers rather than correct answers is too high.

In particular, users have been observed using ChatGPT to farm reputation from low-activity questions with bounties across many StackExchange sites - including ones where they lack the domain expertise or even language comprehension to judge whether the answer is correct - knowing there's a chance their generated answer will be awarded the bounty by default even if it is incorrect. This practice is actively harmful to users posting questions and bounties on this site, so intervention to reduce this abuse of the system is warranted.

For these reasons, we will follow the same [policy announced for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned):

- the use of ChatGPT or similar large language model AI to create posts here on gamedev.stackexchange.com is not permitted.
- Posts created with ChatGPT or AI are subject to deletion without notice.
- If a user is believed to have used ChatGPT after the posting of this temporary policy, sanctions will be imposed to prevent them from continuing to post such content, even if the posts would otherwise be acceptable.

Comment: Related: [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421880/950488)
Do we have a different policy regard that aspect? Does discussing detection / reporting of ChatGTP on GDSE need to be its own post?

Comment: [Similar to the answer at that link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421889/3064164), I think it's best to not publicly disclose all our detection strategies, since that can be used to tailor evasions. For now, if users want to flag content that they believe to be abuse of this technology, the moderators will look into it. We're not asking users to scour all posts for evidence of AI use, but noticeably wrong / unhelpful answers may merit flagging for additional scrutiny.

Comment: I meant more specifically, what action non-mods should take in terms of detection & reporting - that wasn't addressed in the answer, but your reply about flagging pretty much covers it for me.